# Using wp_enqueue_script with social media buttons?

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript, social-sharing

I want to embed a social sharing button in the theme. Following is the standard code to embed the twitter button.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

However, WordPress recommends to use the `wp_enqueue_script` to include any kind of javascript code. So I am wondering how can I include the above script code properly in a WordPress theme?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything between `<script>` & `</script>` in a separate file. Then use  `wp_enqueue_script` with the correct path of the file & dependencies to false. After that you can use only `<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>` to add the tweet button.

Answer (score 0):

All that script does is load in another script, and ensures it's only loaded once per-page.

If this theme is just for yourself, and you're not using other twitter-related plugins, I would just enqueue the script directly & skip the "once" checking.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'twitter-widget', 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' );
```